# Encontrar el Maximo valor de unas filas y arrojar el valor de otra fila

Tags: r

Tengo este data frame

```
predictions <- data.frame(
  "2" = c(0.1),
  "3" = c(0.2),
  "4" =3),
  "5" = c(0.4),
  "6" = c(0.5)
)
```

Quiero buscar el mayor de cada fila y asignarle el numero del encabezado ( En este caso seria 0,5 y por tanto 6). Creando una nueva columna con todos ellos. Seria "Maximo"= c(6)

He probado:

```
predictionsTest$MaxValue <- rowMaxs(as.matrix(predictionsTest))
max_positions <- apply(predictionsTest, 1, which.max)

# y este

predictionsTest$MaxValueFirstRow <- predictionsTest[cbind(seq_along(max_positions), max_positions)]
```

Alguna  otra idea??
Muchas Gracias

Comment: Carlos, tené cuidado con el uso de términos. `predictions` es un dataframe con una única fila (en tu ejemplo), luego, el valor máximo no es 0.5, sino 3 que corresponde a la columna llamada `4` y luego en tu código de ejemplo `predictions` pasa a ser llamado `predictionsTest`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
colnames(predictions)[apply(predictions, 1, which.max)]
```

- Con `apply(predictions, 1, which.max)` "aplicamos por fila (`margin=1`) la función `which.max` que nos retorna el índice del primer elemento que sea el máximo
- Con `colnames(predictions)[ .. ]` obtenemos el nombre de la columna de dicho elemento